# how to have php get the __LINE__ or __FILE__ value where a function is called

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a ZF debug function like this:

```
function fs_d($d, $at){
    if($_REQUEST['debug']=='123'){
        Zend_Debug::dump($d,'at: ' . $at);
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

and will call like this:

```
fs_d($var, $at)
```

what I'd like $at to represent where `$at` was called in the function. In other words, something like `__FILE__` at `__LINE__` that is evaluated at point of function call and NOT at point of output. But I don't want to write `__FILE__` at `__LINE__` at every call.

Is there some way to wrap as a macro, wrap in brackts, `{$}` or backticks or something?

Comment: removed comment as answered below

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://www.php.net/debug_backtrace

```
$backtrace = debug_backtrace(false);
$last = $backtrace[1];
echo "Error in $last[file], line $last[line] ($last[function])!";
```