# Automatically use __LINE__ and __FILE__ relative to where function is called

Tags: php, function

I have a function `log($text)`

all this does is write `$text` to a database.

I would like to include `__LINE__` and `__FILE__`, but don't want to include it as a parameter each time as I currently do:

```
function log($text,$file = null, $line = null){
    // write $text to db using the three paramters
}
```

If I change `$file = null` to `$file = __FILE__` it uses the file name that the function lives in, rather than where the function is being called.

Is there any way around this?

<sub>Although the question is identical, the answers seem to focus on some other topic: [function name($param, $line = __LINE__, $file = __FILE__) {};](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387320/function-nameparam-line-line-file-file)
also, not using Zend framework: [how to have php get the __LINE__ or __FILE__ value where a function is called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184280/how-to-have-php-get-the-line-or-file-value-where-a-function-is-called?rq=1)</sub>

Comment: The question you linked to seems to me to answer the question fine - the key insight is that you need to use [`debug_backtrace()`](http://php.net/debug_backtrace) to find where the function was called from.

Comment: possible duplicate of [function name($param, $line = \_\_LINE\_\_, $file = \_\_FILE\_\_) {};](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387320/function-nameparam-line-line-file-file)

Comment: Ohhh, ok , I didn't get why everyone was using that name I thought it was implied by something else. So that's the function I need to use, aye?

Comment: thanks @IMSoP and thanks for the edit on that question :)